# How to execute code when device is charging and reboot?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I need to call a JSON web service over the web to download and update the device database. It doesn't need to be real time like push notifications, so 1 or 2 days is fine to update the device.

Is there a way activate my code only when the device is charging and on reboot? I figure this would cover my cases for users charging a dead phone. Maybe I need to add another case for when internet is available also?

I am thinking I need a `BroadcastReciver` or a `Service`, but I am not sure which one. Do I need to even use `AlarmManager` since this is not on a schedule?

Comment: You can use BroadcastReceiver. ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED and BOOT_COMPLETED (if you want to run your code after a reboot).  Plenty of info on the web, is there something in particular you are having a problem with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different approach.

1. You can have a small part of the code running as a service in the background http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/service/android-service-example/
2. You can poll the isCharging for Android. As soon as this happens, the activity is started. https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html